# How to stop second event mousewheel before first ends

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got code which make my window scroll from element to element. If I scroll my mousewheel a little bit it works correctly. But if I scroll faster I've got trouble.

```
var currentPosition = 1;
angular.element(document).on("mousewheel DOMMouseScroll", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    var isUp = e.originalEvent.detail < 0 || e.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 ? true : false;

    if (isUp) {
        if (currentPosition > 0) {
            currentPosition--;
            setPoinerActive();
            $scrollHomePage.scrollTo(vm.myIndex[currentPosition]);
        }
    }
    else {
        if (currentPosition < 3) {
            currentPosition++;
            setPoinerActive();
            $scrollHomePage.scrollTo(vm.myIndex[currentPosition]);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer

```
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
            timeout = null;
            return function () {
                var context = this, args = arguments;
                clearTimeout(timeout);
                timeout = setTimeout(function () {
                    timeout = null;
                    if (!immediate) {
                        func.apply(context, args);
                    }
                }, wait);

                if (immediate && !timeout) {
                    func.apply(context, args);
                }
            };
        }
```

Comment: can u create a fiddle?

Comment: What do you see in fiddle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue is called debouncing and you may find quite a bit different versions of it if you google. Basically it has been noticed by twitter when user scrolls down the page, an infinite scroll script was loading more content. But then they noticed by the time script triggers several times when you do it fast enough and causes memory leaks and page unresponsive. so they come up with this idea, debouncing. simply, you add a timer in your function before your run your original event, if timer still exists then you cancel your event. so when you scroll down instead of triggering onscroll event 20 times, with timeout, it triggers every x milisecond N times.

```js
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    var self = this;
    self.timeout = null;
    return function() {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        clearTimeout(self.timeout);
        self.timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            self.timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) {
                func.apply(context, args);
            }
        }, wait);

        if (immediate && !self.timeout) {
            func.apply(context, args);
        }
    };
}
```

Then in your original event listener,

```js
    angular.element(document).on("mousewheel DOMMouseScroll", debounce(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       e.stopPropagation();

       var isUp = e.originalEvent.detail < 0 || e.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 ? true : false;

       if (isUp) {
            if (currentPosition > 0) {
                currentPosition--;
                setPoinerActive();
                $scrollHomePage.scrollTo(vm.myIndex[currentPosition]);
            }
        }
        else {
            if (currentPosition < 3) {
                currentPosition++;
                setPoinerActive();
                $scrollHomePage.scrollTo(vm.myIndex[currentPosition]);
            }
        }
    });
    }, 300));
```

Comment: It's not about scroll on click I put my cod on simple timer but it doesn't work in my project.

Comment: And I use it on angular.element(document).on. If you now what different with this and you example you understand what I mean. So sorry but you cod incorrect.

Comment: Ok, I think there is a miscommunication or misunderstanding here. it is not a simple timer, it is `debounce` function. I put your code in proper place. See if this would work

Comment: But first you need to add that debounce function in your code.

Comment: I've got error  ( Cannot set property 'timeout' of undefined ), dont understand why....

Comment: Yuo answer correct. All work how I need it. Thank you. Give you like. But I make without some code. Look in my question I update it.

Comment: guyfawkes Can you give me you skype. For more communication. :)